# Setting height of UiLabel inside UiStackview Using swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am dynamically adding views in the UiStackview. Since UiStackview is not a regular view, SO I can not add a bottom border to it. That is why I have planned to add a UILabel at the end of it

The label that I will add at the end of my UIStackview will be dealt as a border. I was thinking to make its height as 1point. and give it a background color. And expand its height to full width of screen.

But its height is not getting controlled. Can anyone tell me what the problem is?

Here is the little code snippet

```
let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 1))
            label.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            label.text = ""


            bottomBorder.addArrangedSubview(label)
```

I am adding this in the end of the main stackview. it gets added in the main stackview but with the height of I think 30 point. Or may be its the default height of the UiLabel

My questions are:

1. How to add UiLabel or a border at the end of stackview (vertical alignment)
2. Is there any way that I can add border to my stackview directly? Four side border or at least bottom border?

Answer (score 0):

**You have 2 alternatives to achieve this:**

1- put the stackview inside a UIView `parentView`

[image]

2- do not add `UILabel` directly to the `UIStackView`, add the `UILabel` to `UIView` then add the `UIView` to the `UIStackView`, so that you can whatever separators you want to the `UIView`.

**Code to do that:**

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        stackView.distribution = .fillEqually

        let v1 = getViewForStackView(lblText: "lbl1")
        let v2 = getViewForStackView(lblText: "lbl2")

        stackView.addArrangedSubview(v1)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(v2)
    }


    func getViewForStackView(lblText:String)->UIView
    {
        let rectView = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
        let view = UIView(frame: rectView)
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = lblText
        label.backgroundColor = .red
        addFillingSubview(parentView: view, subview: label, insets: UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8))
        return view
    }

    func addFillingSubview(parentView:UIView, subview: UIView, insets: UIEdgeInsets = .zero)
    {
        subview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        parentView.addSubview(subview)

        let views = ["subview": subview]
        let metrics = ["top": insets.top, "left": insets.left, "bottom": insets.bottom, "right": insets.right]

        parentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "|-(left)-[subview]-(right)-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
        parentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(top)-[subview]-(bottom)-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: views))
    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: I have added a UiView and inside it a UiLabel, so how is distribution property gonna work on uilabel? bcz I want to fix the height of uilabel

Comment: the distribution is related to the UIStackview, you can choose from the right panel (third tab rom the right) the distribution to be fillEqually for example, this way all the subviews will be equally distributed .

Comment: I am adding stackview and all views dynamically

Comment: I haev mainstackview, added through the IB, now in that mainstack view which has vertical allignment, I am adding different views, so between them I want to put separator, so I need a view that has some background but that must have 1 point height. Now you got my problem ?

Comment: check solution number two, put UIView's contains a UILabel's and separators views in the stackView rather than adding the UILabel directly.

Comment: regarding  adding dynamically, you can still adding view dynamically and set the 
stackView.distribution = .fillEqually

create UIView, then label subview  to it with frame less that the height of the the height of the UIView, to act as a separator

Comment: can you just show me how to set the height of the view , wether it is Uiview or UiLabel

Comment: where is the separator ?

Comment: green one !!, is it what u require, if not, enhance the code above to add the necessary subviews .

Comment: that is not even close, its just simple, how to fix the height of a view , just tell me that

Answer (score 0):

Use this class

```
class BorderedStackView: UIStackView {
    let borderWidth : Int = 2
    let borderColor : UIColor = UIColor.darkGray;
    var borderView : UIView!


    required init(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder);
        initializeSubviews();
    }

    required override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame);
        initializeSubviews();
    }

    func initializeSubviews() {
        borderView = UIView.init();
        borderView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black;
        self.addSubview(borderView);
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews();

        var frame = self.bounds;
        frame.origin.y = frame.size.height - CGFloat.init(borderWidth)
        frame.size.height = CGFloat.init(borderWidth);
        self.borderView.frame = frame;
        self.bringSubview(toFront: self.borderView)
    }
}
```

Uses:

```
    let stackView = BorderedStackView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 50, y: 50, width: 200, height: 200));
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.borderWidth = 20;
    stackView.borderColor = .red;
    self.view.addSubview(stackView);

    let subView1 = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100));
    subView1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red;
    stackView.addSubview(subView1);

    let subView2 = UIView.init(frame: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100));
    subView2.backgroundColor = UIColor.black;
    stackView.addSubview(subView2);
```